# Cambiar libreria de Calendario en Ingles a Español

Tags: jquery, librería

Aquí están las imágenes tanto de las fechas de mi sistema y las librerías que uso.

La cuestión es que no tengo idea de como poder cambiar los meses que están en ingles a español, alguna solución o tendría que usar otra librería? Ahi esta el código de la fecha desde-hasta !

[image: Aquí esta la librería del Calendario]

[image: No se donde cambiar para que las fechas que están el ingles me puedan salir en español]

Aquí esta el código del Query , y no se donde cambiarlo , soy un poco novato con querys, así que si me ayudan estaría genial, intente de todo pero no me resultada nada espero alguna posible solución ya que solo esto me falta para poder culminar mi sistema.

```
$(function(){

$('.date-picker-input').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    }
});



$('.dpYears').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    }
});

// month & date only
$('.dpMonths').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    }
});


var checkin = $('.dpd1').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();

    $('.dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('.dpd2').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker');


// inline picker
$('#inline-datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    }
});


// enable clear button
$('#helper-datepicker').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que bajarte la versión correspondiente a tu idioma en [este enlace](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales). Me imagino que la que buscas es la `bootstrap-datepicker.es.js`.

Luego la vinculas en tu html

```
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.es.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

y la inicializas

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'es'
});
```

Comment: Ya intente agregar eso a la query, pero no me resulta o quizás lo agregue mal.